# How to fill ListBox with characters (only lowercase English abc) from actual text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

The task goes like this:

> Create a userform with a listbox, two combo boxes and a command button.
>   The listbox should be filled up with lower case characters (ASCII 97-122 only) from the text, in ascending order and every character should appear only once.

I'm very new to VBA and I'm still trying to figure out the mentality behind programming, but sadly exams won't wait on me. They are ruthless like that.

I was thinking to use the Asc() function in order to fill up the listbox, and I got a basic grip on the For iteration, but I sense I'll need an If selection within a For iteration within a For iteration and that's way beyond my understanding.

As for the rest of the task: ComboBox1 contains string values "Red, Blue, Black", ComboBox2 contains numbers "0, 1, 2" and the commandbutton should do this: the button itself can only be active if there's anything selected in the listbox. If this passes, it should check which color is selected in ComboBox1 and what number is in ComboBox2. then it should check the text in Word for the selected letter and color every word that contains the amount of the selected character in listbox.

English is not my native language, so here's an example:

```
This is a test sentence.

Listbox char selected: e
ComboBox1: Red
ComboBox2: 1
The result should be the "test" word being red.

ComboBox2: 2
The result should be the "sentence" word being red.

ComboBox2: 0
The result should be the "This" "is" "a" words being red.
```

My exam is next week, and I'm really stuck so if anyone could give me the simplest (and shortest if possible) code for this I'd be very grateful, and it would help me a LOT. Thanks in advance!

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initalize()

With UserForm1.ComboBox1
.Additem "Red"
.Additem "Blue"
.Additem "Black"
End With

With UserForm1.Combobox2
.Additem "0"
.Additem "1"
.Additem "2"
End With

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Characters.Count
letter = ActiveDocument.Characters(i)
If letter > "Z" Then
ListBox1.Additem (Trim(letter))
db = db + 1
End If
Next

'Ascending order
ReDim temp(ListBox1.ListCount)
For r = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount
ListBox1.ListIndex = r - 1
temp(r) = ListBox1.Text
Next r
```

Comment: welcome to superuser, please not that this isn't a free code writing service. I think you're supposed to know VBA, so please start solving the problem and anytime you find something difficult just ask and we'll help. Also your question now is too broad, please have a look on [help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I don't know VBA, I'm learning it, and forums like this are the only place I can turn to. My basic area of learning is economy at the university, not IT, yet i have a class like this. I didn't think it's a free code writing service, and I also made progress with the problem. Maybe I asked the question in a wrong way.
What I meant is I understand that there are a few approaches here, and I'd like to get some help deciding which approach is it, and if it proves unsolvable for me, please give me a hand.

Comment: So what does your code do already? Where are you stuck?